# Indexation new sitemap xml

Tags: seo, google-analytics, sitemaps

I have added a new sitemap in Google Search Console 4 weeks ago, but at this moment only 1 url is indexed from the 1298 urls total. Is that normal or is something wrong?

Url new sitemap: www.marington.nl/filter_sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use Fetch as Google in your webmaster tools account to make sure google is using your sitemap.

If your site has few or no good backlinks, then google will not index your site as fast as others.

also for google, www and non-www, http and https are different websites. make sure you have the appropriate website in webmasters.

Comment: Fetch as Google: already done a few times. Also correct https://www.marington.nl in Search Console.

Answer (score 0):

As added aboven i have already used fetch as Google, also correct url in Search Console. Any other ideas or is it normal that after 4 weeks only 1 of 1298 urls is indexed?